# Pictures of the Korean Central Intelligence Agency

Tags: images

I am looking for open (and Wikipedia-usable) pictures describing the [Korean Central Intelligence Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Central_Intelligence_Agency). For instance the building or a plaque in front of it.

The agency has been renamed/transformed, so either old pictures, or new pictures of the building that used to host it, are OK.

Wikipedia Commons has a related category but it contains only a logo (which I guess is not open, only fair-use, and thus not usable everywhere on Wikipedia), a building picture which is tagged for imminent deletion, and watches that are newer than the KCIA:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:National_Intelligence_Service